# load different view files when switching the url

Tags: php, nextcloud

I would like to create a Nextcloud app and followed this tutorial

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/16/developer_manual/app/intro.html

---

After creating the app skeleton I added some routes to **routes.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'routes' => [
       ['name' => 'page#index', 'url' => '/', 'verb' => 'GET'],
       ['name' => 'test#index', 'url' => '/test/:value', 'verb' => 'GET'],
       ['name' => 'user#index', 'url' => '/user', 'verb' => 'GET']
    ]
];
```

---

I created some controllers by following this guide

https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/16/developer_manual/app/requests/controllers.html

My **PageController.php** delivers the index template

```
public function index() {
    return new TemplateResponse('demoappct', 'index');  // templates/index.php
}
```

the **TestController.php** delivers the test template

```
public function index() {
    return new TemplateResponse('demoappct', 'test');  // templates/test.php
}
```

and the **UserController.php** delivers the user template.

---

I extended the **navbar.php** with these routes

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#/">
            Main page
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        Header for grouped links
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#/test/12345">
                    Route with param
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#/user">
                    User Info
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

In the templates folder where **index.php** is I added the view files **test.php** and **user.php**.

I changed the generated **index.php** to

```
<?php
script('demoappct', 'index');
style('demoappct', 'base');
?>

<div id="app">
    <div id="app-navigation">
        <?php print_unescaped($this->inc('nav')); ?>
        <?php print_unescaped($this->inc('settings')); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="app-content">
        <div id="app-content-wrapper">
            <?php print_unescaped($this->inc('index/content')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please have a look at `$this->inc('index/content')`. I created a **content.php** file for each view file I would like to render.

So **test.php** would call

```
<?php print_unescaped($this->inc('test/content')); ?>
```

and **user.php** would call

```
<?php print_unescaped($this->inc('user/content')); ?>
```

These content files are currently empty. They only contain something like

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>
```

---

When I test my app and click on a navigation link the routing doesn’t work. The url changes but only my index file gets rendered.

I thought that when this route `'page#test'` gets called there is a reference to the view file in the templates folder.

What am I missing?